# WP_Query with 2 genres

Tags: wp-query

I'm working with a custom post type and trying to get a query working that includes 2 genres (a custom taxonomy).

I have this, which works for a single genre (I don't want to display the widget currently being viewed in the list, the 'post__not_in' takes care of that).

```
$myposts = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'widgets', 
        'post__not_in' => array($wp_query->post->ID),  
        'genre' => 'styleA' 
    ) 
);
```

But I'm having trouble when I try to make a list that includes 2 genres.

I've tried various versions of this:

```
$myposts = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'post_type' => 'widgets', 
        'post__not_in' => array($wp_query->post->ID),  
        'genre' => array('styleB', 'styleC') 
    ) 
);
```

Everything I've read in the Codex seems to use a syntax like this, anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Much appreciated.

Comment: What is `genre` ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
$myposts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'widgets', 
    'post__not_in' => array($wp_query->post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'styleA', 'styleB' )
        )
    )
) );
```

I'm not sure if you need to add `'relation' => 'OR',` after **line 4**, so try it with/without that (i.e. before the `'tax_query'...` line).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried something like that, but this worked. It was missing the 'array (' just after 'WP_Query (' - so I've added that into your answer.

Comment: Whoopsy! Glad you got it sorted :)